# “Lend someone a hand” x “Give someone a hand”

Tags: word-in-context

I have seen many uses of “lend someone a hand” and “give someone a hand”, and despite the fact the use of the second one seems to be more common, it always seemed to me that they both have the same meaning.

In fact this can be confirmed here: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/give-someone-a-hand

But I found the text below in a book where apparently these expressions are used as if they had different meanings:

*While this book may **lend you a hand** in the journey to greatness, in the end it is you who are going to have to **lend yourself a hand** - and **give yourself a hand** when you deserve it.*

I’m really confused about it. I they really have the same meaning, as I suppose they do, why the use of both expressions in the same sentence as if the had different meanings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean exactly the same thing. If you read sufficient books, you will find the English language being used in every conceivable way, sometimes with great skill and sometimes rather clumsily. Not all writing is grammatical or idiomatic.

In this instance the writer has chosen to try to make a point by using **lend** at the start of the sentence and **give** at the end. He/she chose to phrase it that way when it could easily have been put differently. It's possible to head-scratch over any subtle differences, any possible nuances, but **lend a hand** and **give a hand** come down to the same thing. It's just a matter of choice.

Comment: I think the writer was deliberately using _give someone a hand_ in a different sense: giving applause to somebody.

Comment: @ColinFine I should have spotted that! Touché!